# Error adding skillset to Azure Search Indexer

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-search, azure-python-sdk

I am trying to add a custom skillset to my indexer. I am however facing some issues which I don't know how to solve. My skills:

```py
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-search-documents/azure.search.documents.indexes.models.splitskill?view=azure-python
split_skill = SplitSkill(
    name="split",
    description=None,
    context="/document/reviews_text",
    inputs=[{"name": "text", "source": "/document/content"}],
    outputs=[{"name": "textItems", "targetName": "pages"}],
    text_split_mode="pages",
    default_language_code="en",
    maximum_page_length=1000
)

# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-search-documents/azure.search.documents.indexes.models.azureopenaiembeddingskill?view=azure-python-preview
text_embedding_skill = AzureOpenAIEmbeddingSkill(
    name="embedding",
    description=None,
    inputs=[{"name": "text", "source": "/pages"}],
    outputs=[{"name": "embeddings", "targetName": "embeddings"}],
    resource_uri="xxx",
    deployment_id="yyy",
    api_key="zzz",
)
```

How they are added to an index

```py
# Define the skillset with the text embedding skill
skillset = SearchIndexerSkillset(
    name="my-text-embedding-skillset",
    skills=[split_skill, text_embedding_skill],
    description="A skillset for creating text embeddings"
)
```

The error I get is:

```py
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: () One or more skills are invalid. Details: Error in skill 'embedding': Outputs are not supported by skill: embeddings
Code: 
Message: One or more skills are invalid. Details: Error in skill 'embedding': Outputs are not supported by skill: embeddings
```

Should I create the index first and match the output name to the one in the index? I would be grateful if anybody could point to a good tutorial on this :)

Comment: Yes, create the index first so your skillset has a name to reference.  Here is a sample:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-search-vector-samples/blob/main/demo-python/code/azure-search-integrated-vectorization-sample.ipynb

Comment: I was having the same issue and applied your solution. Now there are no errors, so thank you. However, the Index doesn't show vector embeddings, all other fields are shown. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `name` in the outputs for the AzureOpenAIEmbeddingSkill needs to be the singular `embedding`, as [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-azure-openai-embedding#skill-outputs). You can make the `targetName` whatever you want (to use in later skills/mapping to the index), but the `name` needs to be what is documented.